# Executing script.py for Modeller software through java code

Tags: java, python, bioinformatics

Script file

```
# Homology modeling by the automodel class
from modeller import *              # Load standard Modeller classes
from modeller.automodel import *    # Load the automodel class

log.verbose()    # request ver`enter code here`bose output
env = environ()  # create a new MODELLER environment to build this model in

# directories for input atom files
env.io.atom_files_directory = './:../atom_files'

a = automodel(env,
alnfile  = 'align.ali',     # alignment filename
knowns   = '1GJZ',              # codes of the templates
sequence = 'target')              # code of the target

a.starting_model= 1       
a.ending_model= 10           # index of the first model
# (determines how many models to calculate)
a.make()                            # do the actual homology modeling
```

Code

```
import java.io.*;


public class Demo 
{


        public static void main(String args[])
        {

        try 
        {
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("cmd /c \"C:/model2/script.py\"");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
        }
    }
```

Output

```
                     MODELLER 9.10, 2011/09/28, r8346

 PROTEIN STRUCTURE MODELLING BY SATISFACTION OF SPATIAL RESTRAINTS


                 Copyright(c) 1989-2011 Andrej Sali
                        All Rights Reserved

                         Written by A. Sali
                           with help from
       B. Webb, M.S. Madhusudhan, M-Y. Shen, M.A. Marti-Renom,
            N. Eswar, F. Alber, M. Topf, B. Oliva, A. Fiser,
                R. Sanchez, B. Yerkovich, A. Badretdinov,
                  F. Melo, J.P. Overington, E. Feyfant
             University of California, San Francisco, USA
                Rockefeller University, New York, USA
                  Harvard University, Cambridge, USA
               Imperial Cancer Research Fund, London, UK
          Birkbeck College, University of London, London, UK
```

Error

```
iodataW> Setting io.atomfilesdirectory to a colon-delimited string is deprecated, as it is not robust on Windows systems. Set it to a list of directories instead. For example: env.io.atomfilesdirectory = ['./', '../atomfiles'] openf__E> Cannot open file align.ali: No such file or directory;
```

This code is accessing the modeller program as we can see in the output part, once it starts getting executed it gives an error **align.ali not found** as we can see in the error part. It runs as a stand alone `script.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a path issue. Did you try to use the absolute path to `align.ali` in your python script ?